# Abstract class for builder pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have existing model classes that always use builder pattern like this:

```
public class Model {
    public static class Builder {
        private boolean isValid;
        private List<String> errorMessagesOrNull;

        public Builder setIsValid(final boolean isValid) {
            this.isValid = isValid;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setErrorMessages(final List<String> errorMessages) {
            this.errorMessagesOrNull = errorMessages;
            return this;
        }

        public List<String> getErrorMessages() {
            return this.errorMessagesOrNull == null ? new ArrayList<>() : this.errorMessagesOrNull;
        }

        public Model Build() {
            return new Model(this);
        }
    }

    private boolean isValid;
    private List<String> errorMessages;

    private Model(final Builder builder) {
        this.isValid = builder.isValid;
        this.errorMessages = builder.getErrorMessages();
    }

    public boolean getIsValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public List<String> getErrorMessages() {
        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

As you see, the model classes always have `isValid` and `errorMessages`. I want to write an abstract class to minimize the repeated logic for those model classes.

So I came up like this abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractModel<T extends AbstractModel<T>> {

    public static abstract class Builder<T> {
        private boolean isValid;
        private List<String> errorMessagesOrNull;

        public Builder<T> setIsValid(final boolean isValid) {
            this.isValid = isValid;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder<T> setErrorMessages(final List<String> errorMessages) {
            this.errorMessagesOrNull = errorMessages;
            return this;
        }

        public List<String> getErrorMessages() {
            return this.errorMessagesOrNull == null ? new ArrayList<>() : this.errorMessagesOrNull;
        }

        public abstract T Build();
    }

    private boolean isValid;
    private List<String> errorMessages;

    private AbstractModel(final Builder<T> builder) {
        this.isValid = builder.isValid;
        this.errorMessages = builder.getErrorMessages();
    }

    public boolean getIsValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public List<String> getErrorMessages() {
        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

But it's not really working as I intended.  When I extends the abstract class:

```
public class Model extends AbstractModel<Model> {
    // Empty here since all fields are extended
}
```

I cannot do something like:

```
Model model = new Model.Builder.setIsValid(true).Build();
```

I want the abstract class has `Builder` static class, so that I don't need to write the static class `Builder` every time.

Please advise.

Comment: The `Model` class doesn't even `extend` the `AbstractModel<T extends AbstractModel>` class.

Comment: @Theikon I updated the question - sorry, but please take a look

Comment: Why would you make it internal and static in the first place?

Comment: It's just my preference I guess @YassinHajaj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to implement the `Builder`.

```
public class Model extends AbstractModel<Model>{


    private Model(final Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public static class Builder2 extends AbstractModel.Builder<Model> {

        @Override
        public Model Build() {
            return new Model(this);
        }
    }
}
```

then it possible to call

```
Model model = new Model.Builder2().Build();
```

**EDIT**

Also, the constructor of AbstractBuilder also must be `protected`.

```
  protected AbstractModel(final Builder<? extends Builder<T>> builder) {
        this.isValid = builder.isValid;
        this.errorMessages = builder.getErrorMessages();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. And I don't need to `protected AbstractModel(final Builder<? extends Builder<T>> builder) {...}` - I just have `protected AbstractModel(final Builder<T> builder) {...}` and it's working fine.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is a huge flaw in your logic. The program itself doesn't really make any sense at all. Why do you construct a `Model` with the `Builder` class in the first place? I think it is better to show you how you should have written your program, instead of just "bodging" it together. Alright, let us start with the `Model` class.

Let's say the `Model` class cannot be constructed without a `Builder`. Would it then make sense to add the `Builder` class into the `Model` class? Short answer: no, it wouldn't. Instead, the `Builder` class should contain the `Model` class as a non-static internal class.

```
/**
 * The {@code Builder} can construct new instances of the {@code Model} class.
 *
 * @see Model
 */
public class Builder
{
    private final String[] log;

    /**
     * The {@code Model} class can do something. You can only construct it through a {@code Builder}.
     *
     * @see Builder
     */
    public class Model
    {
        private final Builder builder;

        /**
         * Constructs a new {@code Model} with the specified argument.
         *
         * @param builder the {@code Builder} that constructed the model.
         */
        public Model(final Builder builder)
        {
            this.builder = builder;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the associated {@code Builder}.
         *
         * @return the builder that constructed the model.
         */
        public Builder getBuilder()
        {
            return this.builder;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of the {@code Builder} class with the specified argument.
     *
     * @param log the log of the {@code Builder}.
     */
    public Builder(final String... log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to {@code build} a new instance of the {@code Model} class.
     *
     * @return the constructed {@code Model}.
     */
    public Model build()
    {
        return new Model(this);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the log of the {@code Builder}.
     *
     * @return an log.
     */
    public String[] getLog()
    {
        return this.log;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether or not the {@code Builder} is valid.
     *
     * @return {@code true} when the specified {@code log} is not {@code null}; {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isValid()
    {
        return this.log != null;
    }
}
```

No class other than the `Builder` can construct a `Model`. However, if you construct a new instance of the `Builder` class and get the result of invoking the `build` method, you'll have access to all `public` variables and methods.

If you know want to construct a `Model`, you can do that just like that:

```
Builder.Model model = new Builder().build();
```

If you don't want the `Builder.` prefix, just add an import statement that imports the `Model` class.

```
import organisation.projectname.pathToBuilder.Builder.Model;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but there is an error for the `Model` class: `Implicit super constructor AbstractModel<Model>() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor`.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: That's okay! please educate me :D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I marked the different post as an answer because it's more relevant to the original question.  But I upvoted your answer as well.  I really appreciate your post :)